# How do I configure the network interfaces persistently in CentOS so it will survive a reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I configured a network interface with the following commands:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ip addr add 192.168.9.1/28 dev eth0
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

This works. However, when I reboot the machine I lose all the configurations made. How can I make sure this is persistent? I'm using CentOS 6.3.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016713/how-to-run-command-at-startup-in-linux

Comment: The other (and more correct) option will be setting the corresponding values in your system configuration files. Which Linux distro are you using? (If that's Linux, of course)

Comment: @harish.venkat That's the wrong way to configure things for your network.

Comment: Are you using GUI or a CLI-only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, your given configuration of the default gateway is not valid. `192.168.0.1` is not within the network of `192.168.9.1/28`. I suspect you made a typo, so I assume you meant `192.168.9.10` as the default gateway here.

Referring to the RHEL 6 Deployment Guide [section 8.2](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) for the address and [section 8.4](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) for routes:

1. Create/edit a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` containing:

   ```
   DEVICE=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=none
   ONBOOT=yes
   NETMASK=255.255.255.240 # this is /28
   IPADDR=192.168.9.1
   USERCTL=no
   ```
2. Create/edit the route configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`:

   ```
   default 192.168.9.10 dev eth0
   ```

Comment: @UlrichDangel Good point. Wasn't completely awake I guess. Fixed.

Comment: @gertvdijk got it,just provided a quick fix.